# How to add particular number of rows to a datatable in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have 'n' number of rows in datatable1. Now i want add 'n' number of rows to datatable2.Its notable that two datatables are having different number of columns.Can anyone please help me with c# coding?

I have used following code but it doesn't work.

```
            datatable1 = feeCompBLL.getcommunity();
            foreach (DataRow drow in datatable1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow table2rows = datatable2.NewRow();
                datatable2.Rows.Add(table2rows );

            }
```

Comment: What does or doesn't it do? do you get any errors if so what is the error?

Comment: The object name table2rows is getting overwritten.

Comment: "It doesn't work" - the thing programmers love to hear from users. Nice and descriptive.

Comment: two datatables are having different number of columns

Comment: N number of rows means, Do u want to Copy the rows to the datatable having the same Column name?

Answer (score 2):

You, can use `datatable2 = datatable1.Copy();` to do ur work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

if the two datatables are having different number of columns you should specify the particular colum that you are trying to insert into the "datatable2"

eg

```
foreach (DataRow drow in datatable1.Rows)
{
  DataRow table2rows = datatable2.NewRow();                
  table2rows[columname] = drow[columnname];
  datatable2.Rows.Add(table2rows);            
}
```

that is you will have to assign the correct column name or column number to the new row.

Answer (score 0):

To help you I need some info on the code; 
1. does datatable2 have columns defined 
2. What is FeeSetupRow

If columns are added already, I fee, datatable2.Rows.Add(FeeSetupRow) should be like datatable2.Rows.Add(table2rows).

If you want to copy also the data from datatable1 to datatable2 then you follow as kalyan specified.